# Image source with variable in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I have a api that allows me to get a image name, like this

```
var iconApi = value.icoapi
```

this `value.icoapi` is a dinamic name because I get it from a api, i trying to write a Image code like this

```
<Thumbnail source={require('../assets/imgs/ico.png')} />
```

but I need change this final part "ico.png", change it for my variable, something like this

```
<Thumbnail source={require('../assets/imgs/+ iconApi')} />
```

But returns me error,

thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the value of `icoapi`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass as source the `URI`. It would work if `value.icoapi` is a `http` or better `hptts` link. Please let me know if it works or not and upvote would be nice.

```
<Thumbnail source={{uri: value.icoapi}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve a problem like the one you describe, here I need to change and icon depending on if it is focused or not

```js
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => {
          let source
          if(focused){
            source = require('./src/assets/home-icon-active.png')
          }else{
            source = require('./src/assets/home-icon.png')
          }
          return (<Image source={source} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />)
        }
```

I think it may work like the thing you need

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to put the filename as + iconApi, you should use:

```
<Thumbnail source={require(`../assets/imgs/${iconApi}`)} />
```

This is utilizing the ES6 Template literals. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score -1):

Update as of 2022, maybe somebody will find it useful, it can be adapted to different needs:

I've done it with the useState hooks:

```
const [linkBG, setLinkBg] = useState(require('../assets/2.jpg'))

function BackgroundChange() {
    if (background === 1) {
      setLinkBg(require('../assets/2.jpg'))
    } else if (background === 2) {
      setLinkBg(require('../assets/3.jpg'))
    } else if (background === 3) {
      setLinkBg(require('../assets/4.jpg'))
    }
```

and so on..
}

in the return

```
<ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={`${linkBG}`}>
```

Cheers